# if exists in array } else {

Tags: php

I currently use the following script that checks if a page exists in my array and then opens it, else it opens my error.php

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $pages = array('p_1',
                   'p_2',
                   'p_3',
                   'error');

    if (!empty($page)) {
     if(in_array($page, $pages)) {
        $page .= '.php';
        require_once('../' . $page . '');
    }
     }
    else {
        require_once('../error.php');
    }
?>
```

Accidentally (until now I didn't test it) I added a newpage.php in my site and forgot to add it in my array.

But my script instead of displaying my error.php it opened the newpage.php.

Where did I go wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to say it, but it is not possible. Not in this snippet of code. Search for requiring/including somewhere else

And, error.php shows only in case that `$_GET['page']` is empty

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $pages = array('p_1',
                   'p_2',
                   'p_3',
                   'error');

   if (!empty($page)) {
        if(in_array($page, $pages)) {
                $page .= '.php';
                require_once('../' . $page . ''); 
        }
        else require_once('../error.php');
    }
    else  require_once('../error.php');

?>
```

is correct one

Comment: You 're missing an **else{** but still is not giving the error.php. It displays my newpage.php Ahhhh... You edited it...

Comment: Oh.. I think I found my mistake... I am using jq .load() to load my newpage.php and my jq file doesn't request my "check file"

Comment: Haha. So it's as I said in first sentence. Don't forgot to accept answer if some helped you here

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it opened newpage.php without seeing the rest of your code but i can tell you why it didn't display the error.php page

Your code only display error.php if $_GET['page'] "is empty" (ie null, 0, '').
To fix it you should try the following code :

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];
$pages = array('p_1',
               'p_2',
               'p_3',
               'error');

if(!empty($page) && in_array($page, $pages)) {
    $page .= '.php';
    require_once('../' . $page . '');
} else {
    require_once('../error.php');
}
```

?>